# upgrading the kerner from 5.0.0-37 to 5.3.0-26 on ubuntu 18.04 caused many drivers to not work

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, kernel, touchpad

after updating to the new kernel almost everything is broken including:

- nvidia drivers
- touchpad driver
- wifi driver
- usb ethernet adapter(that I usually use when the wifi drivers are
  broken)

I cant get any networking to work when booted to the new kernel.
I have no idea where to even start with this many problems.

Comment: How did you upgrade kernel? How did you install drivers? It is expected that out-of tree drivers stop working on kernel upgrades.

Comment: Most drivers were installed automatically except the nvidia one, I updated the kernel simply by: sudo apt update sudo apt upgrade. I don't expect that after using apt upgrade almost everything be broken.

Comment: Then the question is too broad. I suggest asking a separate question regarding each device providing as many details as you can. It is wierd that the kernel is 5.3.0-26, the current kernel is 5.3.0-46. Is it a typo?

Comment: 5.3.0-26 is what apt installed and it still doesn't upgrade to anything newer, I wont ask for everithing separately, there is an underlying issue there that causes all this, fixing that most likely going to fix most if not all the issues.